# How do I retrieve value NULL from mySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I know I'm just making a simple error here.  I have a column called ParentEventID that sometimes has a NULL value.  I need to retrieve rows with that value.  My code is only retrieving rows where ParentEventID = "0" right now.

```
$UserID = "118";

$query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID = 'NULL'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['UserID'] . " ".$row['EventName']. " " . $row['ParentEventID'];
    echo "<br />";
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use `IS NULL` instead of `= 'NULL'`

Answer (score 3):

You are currently looking for the string `'NULL'`. Try `IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @Joel Rasika beat David by 1 second :P

Comment: @Joel I think Stack Overflow's sorting function is `return Math.round(Math.random()) - .5` :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL
```